# Write with Java Apache Excel file with item and text component as cell values

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2007

I worte a code, that generated an output, where other people should choose an acknowledgment value 0,1 or 2. But some people ignored the "value rules" and they wrote other things into the cells. Now I want to generate the output with radio buttons and a textfield for comments. It should not be possible anymore to write other things into the `ACKValue` cells.

Is this possible to code with Java Apache? Can somebody give me some keyword how to do it. At the end it should be possible to read in the file again and sort the rows with respect to the chosen value.

[image]

Comment: "At the end it should be possible to ... sort the rows with respect to the chosen value." This is not possible. Even when `apache poi` would be able creating such `ActiveX` or `Form` controls, which it is not, the controls are not really cell content but hover as shapes in the drawing layer over the sheet. Why not using [Data Validation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ss.usermodel) "Drop Down Lists"?

Comment: Thank you. A Drop Down Lists is also a good idea.

Comment: I have to read the link you wrote. But maybe one question, will this method assign the cell value to the chosen value from the list in an easy way?

Comment: It does the same as `Excel`s `GUI` using [Data > Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) Allow > List.

Comment: Another question. Is it possible to color the items of the drop down list. So that is more clear for the user?